# "bash: sysctl: command not found" in debian:stretch-slim

Tags: linux, bash, docker, debian, debian-stretch

when I pull the debian:stretch-slim from hub.docker.com, and then run a container(root), I find that **bash: sysctl: command not found**.

How can I use sysctl in debian:stretch-slim?

and many images are builded from debian:stretch-slim, so when I want to use **sysctl** in some other containers like that:

`docker run --rm -it redis:latest --sysctl net.core.somaxconn=2048 redis-server`

It will throw ERROR message.

It can be tested like:

```sh
docker pull debian:stretch-slim
docker run --rm -it debian:stretch-slim bash
root@7b923f27f7ee:/# sysctl
bash: sysctl: command not found
```

Comment: `apt-cache search sysctl` maybe?

Comment: `root@da79336f6845:/# apt-cache search sysctl`>
`root@da79336f6845:/# sysctl`>
`bash: sysctl: command not found`

Comment: `/sbin/sysctl -a` maybe?

Comment: `root@a5c114840c07:/# /sbin/sysctl -a`>
`bash: /sbin/sysctl: No such file or directory`

Comment: I have checked, the `sysctl` does not exist in these path `/sbin/`,`/usr/sbin/`, and the `$PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: If you really need `sysctl` utility in the container - `apt-get update && apt-get install procps`.

Comment: very good, `apt-get install procps` can work

Comment: For others via google, don't forget it needs to be run as root, so `sudo sysctl net.core.somaxconn=2048` on bare metal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start your container with this command:

`docker run --rm -it  --sysctl net.core.somaxconn=2048 redis:latest redis-server`

`--sysctl` should be docker run's argument and it should not be a command to your `redis` image

Comment: I am having this error in gitlab-ci runner when trying to use `expo` cli. Where should I add this command? at the docker gitlab ci runner level ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Can you create a new thread with some detailed information (command used, error details, etc..)? So that it will help us analyze the issue.

Comment: Docker does not support setting all sysctl values. See this link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime. Certain kernel parameters cannot be set within Docker containers. They need to be set on the host computer